# How to make an USB connected, external Hard Drive (mechanical) to dual boot with Windows 10 Enterprise and Linux?

Tags: linux, windows, hard-drive, boot, partitioning

I have an USB 3 connected, 4Tb Segate Backup Plus Hard Disk. I want to create several partitions and dedicated two of them (≅126 Gb each), one for Windows 10 Enterprise (no home or pro), and other for Linux (any distro will do it but Ubuntu is preferred). I don't want to create a single partition that takes all the space for this. The unit will be connected to any computer so it can boot on either OS (dual boot).

I already tried [diskpart] but after creating the primary partition and trying to make it "active" a message is returned saying that it can not be make active. I check and utility called [wintousb] but it is not free for Windows 10 enterprise. The [GImageX] tool seems to need a single partition occupying the entire disk space, I need to devide the disk in several partitions.

Comment: You can apply .wim images to any partition you want with the DISM tool.  You do understand the performance of either Windows 10 or Linux on an external HDD will extremely poor right?  Like grow a bear, shave it off, and grow it back again slow.

Answer (score -1):

Windows OS' will not boot on external devices (excluding PEBuilder).

Comment: [I don't really agree with this answer.](http://www.intowindows.com/how-to-install-windows-7-to-usb-external-hard-drive-must-read/)  Can you backup your statement?    I will be honest, I have installed Windows on an external HDD before in the past, so I know its possible.  Of course that drive always booted the same computer, being able to boot to any computer, is something else entirely.

Comment: There is [Windows To Go](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_To_Go) as well, which is **designed specifically** to boot and run from USB drives.